# Why does the following code compile without error?

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to java and trying to understand the following. The length of the arrays is not same. The code still executes without any errors. I dont understand why. If someone could clarify.

```
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int [][] a = {{1,2,3},{4,5}};
        a[0] = a[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: In an two dimensional array your are holding references to an one dimensional Array in the first dimension. You basicly just change the reference for `a[0]` to an other array, which is fine.

Comment: Out of interest, are you coming from a C or C++ background?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`a[0]` and `a[1]` are both int arrays (i.e. their type is `int[]`), so one can be assigned to the other, regardless of the lengths of the current arrays they are referring to.

Your code is not very different from the following code :

```
int [] a = {1,2,3};
int [] b = {4,5}
a = b;
```

Or from this code :

```
Object a = ...
Object b = ...
a = b;
```

In both cases (as in your original code) you are changing the value of a reference type variable to refer to a different object.

Comment: Just one more thing to clarify. They are 2D array. `a[0]` refers to `[1,2,3]` and `a[1]` refers to `[4,5]`. So the statement means `[4,5]` = `[1,2,3]` ?

Comment: @JeffBenister A 2D array is merely an array whose element type is also an array. So assigning a[0]=a[1] makes a[0] refer to the same array referred by a[1]. The original array that was referred by a[0] is no longer referred to by any reference.

Comment: Not quite Jeff. You're not assigning values but references to values.

Comment: No, it means that if the reference that points to `[4,5]` is called `x`, then `x` now points to `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: @JeffBenister Take an Array of the Dimension `N`. the first Dimension holds a reference to one or multiple arrays of the Dimension `N-1`. `N-1` holds a reference to one or multiple  arrays with the Dimension `N-2` . The `N` Dimesion finally holds references to the objects it is build of.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a different-sized array to an array (`a[0] = a[1]`) in the same way you can re-assign an array variable like this:

```
int[] x = new int[5];
x = new int[6];
```

So, since this is allowed, there's no problem to assign `a[1]` to `a[0]`.

In the end, it's just a change of the reference that the initial array holds.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike C and C++, a Java "array of arrays" behaves like an one-dimensional array of references, each reference being a reference to a one-dimensional array. Initially,

1. `a[0]` refers to {1, 2, 3}
2. `a[1]` refers to {4, 5}

But the *references* `a[0]` and `a[1]` can be reassigned to any other array of `int`. So a reassignment `a[0] = a[1]` is perfectly valid.